# Function overloading with typescript on a react component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Take a simple react component

```
interface MyProps {
  color: string
  name?: string
  height?: number

  isBoy?: boolean

  // only add the following if isBoy is true
  actionHero: string
  nickname: string
}

function MyComponent(props: MyProps){
   ...
}
```

As you can see, the goal is that `actionHero` and `nickName` are required if `isBoy` is set to true. Otherwise, they aren't used.

I assume this is done via function overloading in typescript but how do you do it in react?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to overload your component in this case.
COnsider this example:

```js
import React from 'react'

type Boy = {
  color: string
  name?: string
  height?: number
  isBoy: false
}

type ExtendedBoy = Omit<Boy, 'isBoy'> & {
  actionHero: string
  nickname: string
  isBoy: true;
}

type Props = Boy | ExtendedBoy;

function MyComponent(props: Props) {
  if (props.isBoy) {
    props.nickname // stirng
  } else {
    props.isBoy // false
  }
  return <div></div>

}

const withBoy = <MyComponent isBoy color="red" actionHero={'batman'} nickname={'qwert'} /> // ok
const withoutBoy = <MyComponent isBoy={false} color="red" /> // ok
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wChSYBPMJOAIQkrgF44BvUuONCAG2gBccAM4wowAHYBzTnAkoQSAPxDR46bIAWSYFM0wVcgK4gARkiizgwhpSGYUvYUlIBfclRpwAogA8YSBIAJkhBtixwAPIgwDAAPLYANATWtvgAfHAAZOyy6DDAEBIAEhYQqmKSMlwSwGgA1vKKFerVcKmMQmJGSADcbh7UtAAKOGDCEeEAPj7%20gSFhjP2kmEYSGIUScACylADCuJASgTAAFGBjwkKjEOMAlLlcwJhw55cAdB2UDxxcXBe3YTvWoNJq0AD04JEBSgGi4rjgSCctF%20fwB40%20NkYcEhcAcyNk7i4RBgRlhcDiQWAADd0nFwVTaeR3KQeBJRHAAO6xTThVhxXYHcBFE7tLFMHj8KDMABERCCMrg%20U2pRwzDY%20FMKBgIBQEnwCJBjQUSHV%20AAjpyLDADTjMriIPVWUUOdyYJoIEYYHyKYLDiKJPAvur8c4EZLoLL5YrwfaoY6gA)

I have used discriminated unions instead function overloading.

**BUT**, nobody can't stop you if you still want to overload your component:

```js
import React, { FC } from 'react'

type Boy = {
  color: string
  name?: string
  height?: number
  isBoy: false
}

type ExtendedBoy = Omit<Boy, 'isBoy'> & {
  actionHero: string
  nickname: string
  isBoy: true;
}

const MyComponent: FC<Boy> & FC<ExtendedBoy> = (props) => {
  if (props.isBoy) {
    props.nickname // stirng
  } else {
    props.isBoy // false
  }
  return <div></div>

}

const withBoy = <MyComponent isBoy color="red" actionHero={'batman'} nickname={'qwert'} /> // ok
const withoutBoy = <MyComponent isBoy={false} color="red" /> // ok
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecBiAwnAL5wBmUEIcA5FKhrQFDMwCeYScAQhO3AC8uZnDhoIAG2gAuOAGcYUYADsA5qLgqUIJAH45i5es0ALJMDWmYBrQFcQAIyRRNweX3ZzyKSfKTMJKwcXHAAogAeMEgqACZIsZ5CcADyIMAwADye2LTunrQAfHAAZCJi6DDAECoAEi4QhkqqGmIqwGgA1tq6TcatcPn8ckp2SADcgawSKopwALLshNSQKjEwckTZ-MVlW5HRcQmexcIAFGBUYPIAlELFOG7kcBdX8gB0Q%20x3j2JilxBru92l0etwAPTghRVKAmMRkJB%20bi-P4AoFfOCQii%20fyaIJiBgwOywuCZWLAABuhUy4PJVNYQWYMzmAHcMqYksJMotluAautBh5%20OIpNBBAAiBixcVwSrVOoNQQ4WiOFAwEAoFS0Mgg7o6JBK2gARxZLhg2sxxSxEE6TJqrPZEDsME5pJ5K35KngXyVPiRZAk0igEqlMvBVqhNqAA)

Please be aware that intersection of functions produces function overloading `FC<Boy> & FC<ExtendedBoy>`

If you are interested in typescript validation in react components, see my [article](https://dev.to/captainyossarian/how-to-type-react-props-as-a-pro-2df2) and my blog [here](https://catchts.com/type-negation) and [here](https://catchts.com/validators)

---

**@NicoRichter** asked a very good question: Why

```js
React.createElement(MyComponent, { isBoy: false, color: 'red' });
```

is failing?

Before answering on this question, just try to change this overloading `FC<Boy> & FC<ExtendedBoy>` to this one `FC<ExtendedBoy> & FC<Boy>`. It might sound strange, but it is a "game changer", because we are dealing with overloadings. When `createElements` infers a props from overloaded function it just grabs last overloading (by design). This is why it does not work in a way we expect.

Example:

```js
function foo(a: string): number
function foo(a: number): string
function foo(a: number | string) {
  return null as any
}

const fn = <Fn extends (...args: any[]) => any>(fn: Fn,...props:Parameters<Fn>) => {

}

const result = fn(foo,2) // ok, expects number
```

Comment: But why is the following not possible? Shouldn't it be the same? `const withoutBoy2 = React.createElement(MyComponent, {isBoy: false, color: "red"});`

Comment: @NicoRichter what exactly is not possible? Could you please share an example ?

Comment: Playground if forked from yours, see on this playground last line: https://tsplay.dev/wOl7rN

Comment: @NicoRichter answer is updated. Thank you for a good question!

Comment: But now the opposite withBoy2 isn't working anymore, see tsplay: https://tsplay.dev/w1n5YN

Comment: @NicoRichter yes, this is because order is matter `FC<ExtendedBoy> & FC<Boy>` when you overload a function

Comment: But shouldn't both of them work like their jsx-variant two lines above? Both jsx are valid, but only one React.createElement is working.

Comment: @NicoRichter please see [this](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26591). When you call `createElement` it infers a react component function signature which is overloaded. When you infer overloaded signature you are infering only one function signature, not both

Answer (score 0):

It's possible since types have no conditional logic and can't depend on each other with but two mapped types instead. One for the optional properties, and one for the required ones.

```
interface MyProps {
    color: string
    name?: string
    height?: number
    isBoy?: false | null
}

interface MyProperRequired extends MyProps {
    isBoy: true
    // only add the following if isBoy is true
    actionHero: string
    nickname: string
}

function MyComponent(props: MyProps | MyProperRequired) {

}


MyComponent({ color: "red", height: 1, name: "hi", isBoy: true })
```